# Access CURRENT src in embed object HTML

Tags: javascript, html, embed

I have created an embed object in HTML and this code in Javascript:

```js
function mainLoop() {
  var browser = document.getElementById("browser");
  console.log(browser.src);
}

//call main loop
setInterval(mainLoop, 1000);
```

```html
<embed src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page" id=browser>
```

When I run the webpage, the console constantly prints `"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"`, which is what is expected. However, when I click on a link inside the embed HTML to change the webpage inside the embed HTML, the console continues to print `"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"`.

How do I access the current URL of the content inside of the embed HTML?

(I cannot use `browser.contentWindow` because of a Security Error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately due to CORS, this is impossible. Perhaps find a different way of doing this, or make a page similar to the one shown.

You cannot access the `src` of an `iframe` that is from another domain.